# CocoaPods dependency require a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

How to find out which iOS version you need to set when you see such a message

I can do it manually, step by step increasing the target version. But i think there should be an easier way

Comment: Go through all the pods and see what version they require? Not sure if that’s an ”easier” way. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @Sweeper the "easiest" way is exactly what is asked in the question. I have dozens of dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pod install --verbose | grep 'Installing target' | grep -oe '[[:digit:]]*\.[[:digit:]]*' | sort -rn | head -n 1
```